# reloading the page images should be selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, json

what I have to archive:

- toggle the images with a selected class
- reload the page, the previously selected pictures should be remembered.

Issues that I'm having:
The myPhotos array is not taking each 'selected' item... its looping the elements with the class 'selected' but adding the same one each time.

The second problem is that the displayPhotos function will need to be changed to display all images every time..
but leave the ones selected on refresh

please help.

I've created a fiddle, incase the code below doesn't work.
https://jsfiddle.net/1mes2z6s/1/

```js
// Creates an empty array for selected photos to be added to
myPhotos = [];

// ---------------------------------------------
// Callback function to get photos from flickr
// ---------------------------------------------
(function() {

  //changed the callback so that it is defined
  window.cb = function(data) {
    //user returned data 
    displayPhotos(data);
  }

  var tags = "london";
  var script = document.createElement('script');

  script.src = "https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?format=json&jsoncallback=cb&tags=" + tags;
  document.head.appendChild(script);


})();

// ------------------------------------
// Display photos
// ------------------------------------
function displayPhotos(data) {
  var $images = $('#images');

  // Check if localStorage key is empty (e.g. no photos have previously been selected) and go and get some
  if (localStorage.getItem("mySavedPhotos") === null) {

    // loop through photos in the JSON endpoint
    for (var i = 0; i < data.items.length; i++) {
      $('<img/>').attr('src', data.items[i].media.m).appendTo($images);
    }

    // localStorage key has items, so show them instead    
  } else {

    // retrive the items in localStorage
    var len = JSON.parse(localStorage['mySavedPhotos']).length
    var item = JSON.parse(localStorage['mySavedPhotos'])

    // loop through photos in local storage
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      $('<img/>').attr('src', item[i]).appendTo($images);
    }
  }
}

// ------------------------------------
// Add 'selected' class to photo, push it to the 'myPhotos' array, then add array to localStorage
// ------------------------------------
function selectPhoto(photo) {


  // add 'selected' class to image
  photo.addClass('selected');

  // push the 'src' of that image to the array
  myPhotos.push(photo.attr('src'));

  var mySavedPhotos = myPhotos;

  // JSON stingify the items in local storage so they can be accessed easily
  localStorage['mySavedPhotos'] = JSON.stringify(mySavedPhotos);

  // debug
  // console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage['mySavedPhotos']));

}

// ------------------------------------
// JQUERY DOM LOADED
// ------------------------------------
$(function() {

  // When user clicks on photo to select
  $('#images').on('click', 'img', function() {

    selectPhoto($(this));

  });

  // Clear the local storage items (for debug)
  $('#debugBtn').on('click', 'button', function() {
    localStorage.removeItem("mySavedPhotos");
    console.log(localStorage);
  });

});
```

```css
   div#images img {
     width: 100px;
     height: 100px;
     margin: 10px;
     border: 3px solid #fff;
   }
   div#images img.selected {
     border: 3px solid #f06;
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- this is where the photos will be displayed -->
<div id="images"></div>

<!-- this is a button to clear localStorage items and is for debugging -->
<div id="debugBtn">
  <button>Remove LocalStorage Key</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you reloading the page? Can you not make an AJAX call to fickr API and update UI accordingly?

Comment: @AdamJeffers I need to be able to remember the selected images after refreshing

Comment: Yeh sure I get that... I'm just wondering whether you need to bother 'refreshing' the page at all? Can you describe the scenario?

Comment: @AdamJeffers not hard to follow ... if user comes back to this page OP wants state maintained

Comment: @AdamJeffers User should be able to see selected images if page is refreshed. At the moment only the once selected are visible, I need to see all plus the non selected

Comment: @charlietfl correct,

Comment: Demo seems to work for me. Not clear what the specific problem is or steps needed to replicate it

Comment: @charlietfl  At the moment only the selected one are visible, on refresh. Aslo They should be toggleble

Comment: OK then approach is wrong. You need to loop through all the data from api in both of your cases and see if the src is in the stored data

Comment: @charlietfl would u be able to help? also the toggle class seems to be a bit tricky

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want, Look at this working solution [here](https://jsfiddle.net/1mes2z6s/12/)

**HTML**

```
<!-- this is where the photos will be displayed -->
<div id="images"></div>

<!-- this is a button to clear localStorage items and is for debugging -->
<div id="debugBtn">
  <button>Remove LocalStorage Key</button>
</div>
```

**Jquery**

```
// Creates an empty array for selected photos to be added to
myPhotos = [];
if (localStorage['mySavedPhotos'])
  myPhotos = JSON.parse(localStorage['mySavedPhotos']);

// ---------------------------------------------
// Callback function to get photos from flickr
// ---------------------------------------------
(function() {

  //changed the callback so that it is defined
  window.cb = function(data) {
    //user returned data 
    displayPhotos(data);
  }

  var tags = "london";
  var script = document.createElement('script');

  script.src = "https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?format=json&jsoncallback=cb&tags=" + tags;
  document.head.appendChild(script);


})();

// ------------------------------------
// Display photos
// ------------------------------------
function displayPhotos(data) {
  var $images = $('#images');

  // Check if localStorage key is empty (e.g. no photos have previously been selected) and go and get some
  if (localStorage.getItem("mySavedPhotos") === null) {

    // loop through photos in the JSON endpoint
    for (var i = 0; i < data.items.length; i++) {
      $('<img/>').attr('src', data.items[i].media.m).appendTo($images);
    }

    // localStorage key has items, so show them instead    
  } else {

    // retrive the items in localStorage
    var len = JSON.parse(localStorage['mySavedPhotos']).length
    var item = JSON.parse(localStorage['mySavedPhotos'])
    for (var i = 0; i < data.items.length; i++) {
      // loop through photos in local storage
      //console.log($.inArray(data.items[i].media.m, item));
      if ($.inArray(data.items[i].media.m, item) >= 0) {
        $('<img/>').attr('src', data.items[i].media.m).addClass('selected').appendTo($images);
      } else {
        $('<img/>').attr('src', data.items[i].media.m).appendTo($images);
      }
    }

    //console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage['mySavedPhotos']));
  }
}

// ------------------------------------
// Add 'selected' class to photo, push it to the 'myPhotos' array, then add array to localStorage
// ------------------------------------
function selectPhoto(photo) {

  if (photo.hasClass('selected')) {
    photo.removeClass('selected');
    myPhotos = jQuery.grep(myPhotos, function(value) {
      return value != photo.attr('src');
    });
    localStorage['mySavedPhotos'] = JSON.stringify(myPhotos);
  } else {
    // add 'selected' class to image
    photo.addClass('selected');

    // push the 'src' of that image to the array
    myPhotos.push(photo.attr('src'));

    var mySavedPhotos = myPhotos;

    // JSON stingify the items in local storage so they can be accessed easily
    localStorage['mySavedPhotos'] = JSON.stringify(mySavedPhotos);

    // debug
    // console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage['mySavedPhotos']));
  }
}

// ------------------------------------
// JQUERY DOM LOADED
// ------------------------------------
$(function() {

  // When user clicks on photo to select
  $('#images').on('click', 'img', function() {

    selectPhoto($(this));

  });

  // Clear the local storage items (for debug)
  $('#debugBtn').on('click', 'button', function() {
    localStorage.removeItem("mySavedPhotos");
    console.log(localStorage);
  });

});
```

what you were doing was `myPhotos = [];` which afterwards assigned to `localStorage` which is why every time you refresh the new data is used and the old one is lost

Comment: @user3699998 this is the edited code i hope this is what you want.. https://jsfiddle.net/1mes2z6s/12/

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly I think you want something like this:

```
function displayPhotos(data) {
    var $images = $('#images');
    var savedPhotos = []; // default to empty array
    var localPhotos = localStorage.getItem("mySavedPhotos");

    if (localPhotos) {
        savedPhotos = JSON.parse(localPhotos);
    }

    // loop through photos in the JSON endpoint
    for (var i = 0; i < data.items.length; i++) {
        var src = data.items[i].media.m;
        var $img = $('<img/>').attr('src', src);
        // add selected class if it is in our storage array
        if ($.inArray(src, savedPhotos) !== -1) {
            $img.addClass('selected')
        }
        $img.appendTo($images);
    }   

}
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/1mes2z6s/4/)**</kbd>

Comment: works like mine, if I select then refresh I can only see the selected ones. and it doesn't toggle

Comment: As for toggle you need to remove the item from array. First get the index, then use [Array.prototype.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Comment: I see:-)  looks like If I select then refresh then select something else doesnt remember the previous selected one.

Comment: I never used array.splice before:-(

Comment: OK...I might have messed up your `myPhotos` variable. Is this how you display is expected to work?

Comment: Yes it's fine the selected one should be always remembered. but I must toggle that class too

Comment: would you be able to have a look at this for me please?

Comment: I have worked out the solution for you have a look at the answer i have posted @user3699998